Problem converting SQL to LINQ query using a Join on multiple fields and coalesce
I am trying to convert the below SQL statement to an EF Core Linq query that will utilize a Join om multiple fields with Coalesce (??).
var query2 = 
    from t1 in _dbContext.table1
    join t2 in _dbContext.table2
        on new { t1.SiteId, t1.DepartmentId } 
        equals new { SiteId = t2.SiteId ?? t1.SiteId, DeptID = t2.DeptId ?? t1.DepartmentId }
    where t1.Id == request.Id && t2.UserID == request.userId 
        && (t2.IsRestricted == 1 ? t1.CreatedBy == t2.UserID : t2.UserID == request.userId)
    select t1;

The issue is that the t1.references in the equals new {} after the coalesce (??) operator are giving me the following error
The name 'ti' is not in scope on the right side of 'equals'. Consider swapping the expressions on either side of 'equals'.
Here is the SQL statement I'm trying to convert
SELECT DISTINCT
    t1.*
FROM 
    table1 t1
INNER JOIN
    table2 t2
ON
    t1.SiteId = COALESCE(t2.SiteId, t1.SiteId)
AND
    t1.DepartmentId = COALESCE(t2.DeptID, t1.DepartmentId)
WHERE
    (t1.Id = @Id) AND (t2.UserID = @USERID) AND (CASE t2.IsRestricted WHEN 1 THEN t1.CreatedBy ELSE @USERID END = t2.UserID)

Any suggestions? Thx

Use another join syntax as described in EF Core documentation Collection selector references outer in a where clause
var query2 = 
    from t1 in _dbContext.table1
    from t2 in _dbContext.table2
        .Where(t2 => t1.SiteId == t2.SiteId ?? t1.SiteId && t1.DepartmentId == t2.DeptId ?? t1.DepartmentId)
    where t1.Id == request.Id && t2.UserID == request.userId 
        && (t2.IsRestricted == 1 ? t1.CreatedBy == t2.UserID : t2.UserID == request.userId)
    select t1;

